# compare two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare two strings and decide if they are not equal. I have the code below, but it seems that it is not returning what I want, is this correct?

```
if ((current.request.requested_for != reviewer) && (current.request.requested_for != approver)) {
     return 'Yes';
  }
  return 'No';
```

}

Here reviewer and approver, are some strings that I have declared in lines prior to the if conditions. Basically, my question here is to know if I should use **!=** to check if 2 strings are not equal.

Thanks

Comment: `!==` would be a bit better, but thats not a matter here. Your code does work, this is either a logical error, or you are not handling strings here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have strings in the variables reviewer, approver and the object current.request.requested_for, you can just compare two strings with === which compares type and value. If you compare with ==, you are just comparing the value, there are more reasons about == is returning true for '2' == 2, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).

So, your code could be more declarative and simpler

```
(...)
    const SEARCH = [reviewer, approver];
    return SEARCH.includes(current.request.requested_for)
(...)
```

If your are not using latest javascript do not worry, you could achieve the same with an [array declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) and the [indexOf() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf). They are the former way of the code.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, seems that this is working now :) Cheers